# how to using ImmutableJS in redux reducer?

Tags: reactjs

I was doing a interview react code demo, which is required to use ImmutableJS in the reducer and selectors. But when I when I create my reducer using fromJS, and use state.get("loading", true), it give me an error: `TypeError: state.set is not a function.`. And in the sample reducer they give, it just use state.set(), and it is good, and I saw that the sample reducer and my own reducer are in the same level after combineReducer, so what is the problem?

This is for building redux reducer using ImmutableJS and combineReducer.

This is the combineReducer usage.

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, combineReducers } from "redux";
const appReducer = combineReducers({
  router: connectRouter(history),
  ...Object.keys(Core).reduce((accum, key) => {
    accum[key] = Core[key].reducer;
    console.log(accum);
    return accum;
  }, {})
});
```

My own reducer:

```
const initialState = Immutable.fromJS({
  fetchingRepos: false,
  routes: [],
  error: null
});
const reducer = {};

reducer[action.FETCH_REPOS] = (state, action) => {
  // console.log(action);
  return state.set("fetchingRepos", false);
};
```

Sampe reducer:

```
const reducer = {};
const initialState = Immutable.fromJS({
  signedIn: false,
  details: {}
});

reducer[actions.TOKEN_RECEIVED] = (state, event) => {
  return state
    .set("logIn", true)
    .set("details", Immutable.fromJS(event.user));
};
```

I don't know what is the problem that the sample reducer using state/set() is fine, but my own throw an error!

TypeError: state.set is not a function

```
  27 | 
  28 | reducer[action.FETCH_REPOS] = function (state, action) {
  29 |   // console.log(action);
> 30 |   return state.set("fetchingRepos", false);
  31 | };
  32 |
```

Comment: Just as a reference: https://redux.js.org/recipes/using-immutablejs-with-redux

Comment: It works now. The reason it throws this error is that in my store when it is created, we use state persist in the local data site, so at the very first, I write my sub state as regular object, and it is persistanted in the chrome, and every time it will be updated as plain JS object, so even I build the state as immutable object, it throws the error, because it is regular JS object.